# How to make 1 css value dependent on another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a header with three sections. (all section are lined up horizontally) I want the middle section to adjust depending on the size of the content (text) within it. When I adjust this middle size, I want the other two to adjust accordingly so that the three sections always take up the full width of the site and stay even. my site width is 1000px, this is how I have it set up

```
< div .side_header>  < div #header>   < div .side_header>
```

I want to make a script that says something along the lines of:
  "the width of .side_header equals (1000px minus the width of #header)*.5"
This is what I wrote but my syntax is off:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".side_header").css("width", "$("#header_text").css("width") * .5");  
    })
</script>
```

css:

```
        #title{

        }

        .side_header{
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:#999;
        }

        #header_text{
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:#3FF;
        }
```

html:

```
        <div id="title">
            <div class="side_header">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="header_text"> Header text</div>
            <div class="side_header">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

RESOLUTION:
Using javascript to make dependent values can be troublesome and can result in errors easily. It is better to use a css perpricessor like .less or .sass

Comment: You should also have a look at less. It is a css precompiler which allows you to define variables and do calculations inside of your css code. This Less-Css then gets compiled into 'real' css. No Javascript needed on the client. http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-variables

Comment: Absolutely perfect!! This is exactly what i needed. Thanks so much!! .less is supported by all browsers right? And whats the difference between .less and .sass?

Comment: As less is a css-preprocessor, yes, it is supported by all browsers. What you get when you compile your .less files is pure css; you do not serve .less files to the browsers.
`sass` is just another tool for writing css. There are many like less and sass out there, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411066/less-vs-sass-vs

Comment: Just as a remark: You will need to put some effort into learning less, setting it up, etc. But in the end, it will most likely pay off - cleaner style, faster website, plus you got to know some new stuff, which is always great! :) (this is true for other css frameworks as well, of course - i.e. sass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get what you exactly want to do but just keep in mind that $.css("width") returns the CSS width of an element and not the actual width of it. So if you are trying to set the sidebars width as to occupy the rest of the page width available to them you should use $.width() to read the middle div width.

```
$(".side_header").css("width",((1000 - $("#header_text").width())/2) + 'px');
```

It is even better to use .outerWidth() as CSS wise they can be different. You can find docs about them on the following pages:

http://api.jquery.com/width/
http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

But after all if you want to position some div horizontally this is not a really good strategy. the width() method also works somehow not satisfactory as your CSS styling might be in a way that affects the middle div width itself. Using solid percentage width is more stable than using JS to achieve this.

Comment: It didnt work, could you check my question again? I added html and css. Also, i decided not to use a defined page width, i want the header to span the entire page. The only difference is using $(document).css("width") instead of 1000 right?

Comment: Also, if I use precentages (which i can do), how can i use js to make the side headers automatically adjust is i change the width % of the center header. i have it doing (100%  - $("#header_text").width())/2  but it doesnt work

Comment: By using percentages I meant it is much better idea to se some fixed percentages rather than going JS width calculation.
So if you set some percentage to all of the divs and give them float:left is better. for instance set all of them to width:30%;float:left;

Comment: Percentages work fine when I do them manually. I want to top part to take up the full width of the screen but if somebody has a huge screen I still want the middle section to be about 200px and if i do % it will be larger and smaller depending on the screen. I just want to width of the side parts to change depending on how wide the screen is and the 'px' you added didnt help anything :/

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the width to a string. Try

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".side_header").css("width", ($(document).css("width") - $("#header_text").css("width")) * .5);  
})
</script>
```

Comment: What if i wanted to make the header stretch the entirety of the screen. how could i do:
width of screen minus width of center, times .5

Comment: It didnt work, im going to update my question with my css and html